# Error: Cannot Get on a POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send an POST request in my template through an href:

```
 <% if (typeof(errors) != 'undefined'){ %>
            <% for (var i in errors){ %>
                <h3><% errors[i].message %></h3>
            <% } %>
      <% } else{ %>
            <table border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            <% for (var i in animals){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='/animals/<%= animals[i]._id %>'><%= animals[i].name %></a></td>
                                                                                         <------------This link---------------->
                        <td><a href='/animal/edit/<%= animals[i]._id %>'>Edit</a> <a href='/animal/delete/<%= animals[i]._id %>'>Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
            <% } %>
            </table>        
        <% } %>
```

And I'm handling this link in my server.js:

```
app.post('/animal/destroy/:id', function (request, response)
{
    Animal.remove({ _id: request.parmas.id }, function (err)
    {
        response.redirect('/');
    })
})
```

When the link clicked, I get the following error:

```
Cannot GET /animal/destroy/<id>
```

Comment: Try changing you route (`app.post(...)`) from POST to GET (`app.get(...)`). When you click a link (href) it sends a GET request, instead of a POST.

Comment: Also, the HREF says `delete` but the route says `destroy`.

Comment: clicking on a link will send GET request. You should consider sending POST request via html form tag or xmlhttprequest. I don't recommend changing a route to GET if it is mutating any state on the server.